# Как изменить место сборки артефакта target в intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Постоянно, при пересборке артефакта слетает место сборки артефакта в папку `target` в корневом каталоге по дефолту, а мне нужно что бы оно собиралось в папку сервера `jboss`.

Почему так, и как можно настроить место сборки по умолчанию для проекта?

Comment: это бага идеи. Сам с таким сталкиваюсь. Надо писать в JetBrains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изменить целевую папку, которая по умолчанию `target` в `pom.xml` надо изменить некоторые свойства:

```
<build>
   <directory>jboss</directory>
   ...
</build>
```

Это свойство будет использоваться когда вы запускаете цель `war:war` для `maven-war-plugin-3.2.1`. Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html).